# SpringBoot security : Issue while showing login page in Angular 8

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am implementing login functionality for my project. In frontend I am using Angular 8.
I have implemented in such way so Angular 8 and Springboot is running on same port 8090.

I have routing as

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: EmployeeComponent,canActivate:[AuthGaurdService] },
  { path: 'addemployee', component: AddEmployeeComponent,canActivate:[AuthGaurdService]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent,canActivate:[AuthGaurdService] },
];
```

Java side : I have already set it to permit all /login request

WebSecurityConfig

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)
        throws Exception
    {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            // dont authenticate this particular request
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
            // store user's state.
            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

but still while calling for localhost:8090/login, i am facing on browser

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Feb 26 14:42:50 IST 2020 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

In backend, I am facing

> 2020-02-26 14:30:44.045  WARN 5184 --- [nio-8090-exec-1]
>   org.freelancing.utils.JwtRequestFilter   : JWT Token does not begin
>   with Bearer String 2020-02-26 14:42:49.945  WARN 5184 ---
>   [nio-8090-exec-3] org.freelancing.utils.JwtRequestFilter   : JWT Token
>   does not begin with Bearer String 2020-02-26 14:42:51.287  WARN 5184
>   --- [nio-8090-exec-4] org.freelancing.utils.JwtRequestFilter   : JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String

I think it is going in this block

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException,
        IOException
    {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
        {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try
            {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            }
            catch (ExpiredJwtException e)
            {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }
        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)
        {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
            // authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails))
            {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,
                                                            userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

what I need is to render the login page and then take the credential and create the header.But even on hitting localhost:8090/login it is asking for header in above code as the header is null that's i am getting error:

> JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String

LoginComponent

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    User Name : <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username">
    Password : <input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
  </div>
  <button (click)=checkLogin() class="btn btn-success">
    Login
  </button>
</div>
```

new to security stuff, Please help

Comment: Check that, when you call "localhost:8090/login" in your Angular App, the LoginComponent is requesting the route "/login" to your backend.

Comment: no , it is rendering the fields for username and password

Answer (score 0):

I assume your angular application won't show at all when calling it. You should not try to run two different services on the same port on the same machine, since your browser will not be able to differ what service should get your requests.

Currently you are sending a GET-Request to your API (URL:*/login) which you may not have set. Therefore you'll get the 404 in the error message, but you expect the request to be directed to your angular app to show your application (e.g. login mask).

Comment: we can have angular 8 and springboot on same port, but yes URL should be different for the routes in Angular and URL in controller of springboot

Comment: Please clarify if you're deploying your angluar app through spring boot or if both are separated services. In the later case you do not want to specify the same port.

Comment: deploying on same port. for reference https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-deployment